# RF direct conversion down to DC and signal recovery from IQ

Tags: demodulation, software-defined-radio

I've previously worked with super-heterodyne receivers where the IF spectral content has been above DC.

Reading the below tutorial; direct down conversion receivers are used to mix a signal of interest down to base-band. Figure 7 shows the output of the direct conversion process where the modulated signal has its frequency content either side of DC i.e. half as negative frequencies.
https://www.microwavejournal.com/articles/3226-on-the-direct-conversion-receiver-a-tutorial

A similar question was asked in the link below which explains that there will be indeed overlap and corruption because of the negative frequencies.
[Downconversion / Demodulation of RF signal to DC](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35807/downconversion-demodulation-of-rf-signal-to-dc)

If that is the case, how is the signal recovered and what do the resultant I and Q samples look like in terms of magnitude and frequency content?

If specifics help; if we assume an already modulated carrier 1500MHz with +/-1MHz FSK signal is mixed with a 1500MHz LO. The output (and image) will be centered around DC but half the signal bandwidth will be negative, the missing half will be on-top. Its this with which I'm confused.

Comment: Hi! That answer applies 100% to your question, so I'm not sure in which way yours isn't answered by that – it 1. describes how the I and Q look in spectrum, 2. it explains how the signal is "recovered" (there's really no recovery – I and Q *are* the signal, without anything needing recovery).

Comment: [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/7612/11256) may help you see how quadrature demodulation can recover all information in the signal despite the "spectral overlap".

Comment: OK, re-read the answer. So because there is a phase shift before both are shifted down, the lower half is lost from I and the upper half from Q, which is flipped due to being out of phase, both are recovered.